# Terraform keyvault definitition having problems

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm getting the following error when I run terraform plan for a Azure keyvault definition.

```
│ Error: Key Vault (Subscription: "<removed>"
│ Resource Group Name: "aazurerm_kubernetes_cluster.demo.k8s-resources"
│ Key Vault Name: "tfkv") was not found
│ 
│   with data.azurerm_key_vault.demo,
│   on data.tf line 10, in data "azurerm_key_vault" "demo":
│   10: data "azurerm_key_vault" "demo" {
```

The code is pretty simple.

```
# Set up the key vault
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "demo" {
  name                        = "tfkv"
  location                    = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name         = "${var.resGroup}"
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  sku_name = "standard"
}
```

That code alone runs fine, it's when I try to reference the resource that the error occurs.

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "demo" {
  name                = "tfkv"
  resource_group_name = "${var.resGroup}"
}
```

Comment: Why do you use data source `azurerm_key_vault`, if you already have a resource for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to execute the terraform steps for achieving the Azure Key Vault definition and I successfully executed the `terraform` commands.

I have referred the code from this [official Terraform Resource azurerm_key_vault document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/key_vault) & [[official Terraform Data Source: azurerm_key_vault document]](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/key_vault) and modified it accordingly.

The module mentioned in the question.

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "demo" {
  name                = "tfkv"
  resource_group_name = "${var.resGroup}"
}
```

It was not worked for me as well, so I ended up modifying the modules as per the requirement and was able to produce the output you're looking for.

Here as the requirement was to access the existing azurerm_key_vault I included the output module in `data "azurerm_key_vault"`  so that we will be able to view the targeted key vault at the output.

This is the main reason for causing the error mentioned while trying to access the key vault which can be overcome by the code mentioned below.

**My [main.tf](http://main.tf/) code:-**

```
provider  "azurerm" {

features {

key_vault {

purge_soft_delete_on_destroy  =  true

recover_soft_deleted_key_vaults  =  true

}

}

}

  

data  "azurerm_client_config"  "current" {}

  

resource  "azurerm_resource_group"  "example" {

name  =  "demorgvk"

location  =  "East US"

}

  

resource  "azurerm_key_vault"  "example" {

name  =  "vkbollikeyvault"

location  =  azurerm_resource_group.example.location

resource_group_name  =  azurerm_resource_group.example.name

enabled_for_disk_encryption  =  true

tenant_id  =  data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id

soft_delete_retention_days  =  7

purge_protection_enabled  =  false

  

sku_name  =  "standard"

  

access_policy {

tenant_id  =  data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id

object_id  =  data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

  

key_permissions  =  [

"Get",

]

  

secret_permissions  =  [

"Get",

]

  

storage_permissions  =  [

"Get",

]

}

}

  

data  "azurerm_key_vault"  "example" {

name  =  "vkbollikeyvault"

resource_group_name  =  "demorgvk"

}

  

output  "vault_uri" {

value  =  data.azurerm_key_vault.example.vault_uri

}
```

**Output:**

While executing `terrafrom_plan`
[image]

While executing `terraform_apply`
[image]

[image]

[image]

By using the script, I successfully performed all terraform steps and the desired output.